# How to get the linear combination of a k-form?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, multilinear-algebra, differential

Let M be a smooth manifold then a k-form on it is defined as follows:

$w: M \rightarrow \Lambda^k T_p M \\ p \mapsto w_p$

Where $w_p$ is a k-form on the tangent space. We call such an element differentiable if and only if for all k-tuples $(v_1,...,v_k)$ with $v_i \in T_p M$ the transformation

$w_p: T_pM \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

is differentiable for every such k-tupel.

Further we call the the elements $w_{i_1...i_k}:=w(e_{i_1},...,e_{i_k}): U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ the compnentfunctions of $w$ with a basis B of $\mathbb{R}^n$ so that $B=(e_1,...,e_n)$.

Then we might write $w$ as follows:

$w=\sum_{i_1<...<i_k} w_{i_1...i_k} dx^{i_1}\wedge...\wedge dx^{i_k}$

with the componentfunctions as defined above and $dx^{i_1}\wedge...\wedge dx^{i_k}$ as elements of the basis of $\Lambda^kT_pM$.

I know that we get every k-form as linear combination of the elements I wedged there together with the $w_{i_1...i_k}$ being scalars.

My question is now: Why are the scalars now that we look at the k-form on a smooth manifold functions and not scalars?

My hypothesis is that we look at $w_{i_1...i_k}$ as function of p, thus to say that we locked some argument values $(v_1,...,v_k)$ and do only insert p.

Comment: Your understanding of the meaning of differentiability is wrong. $\omega_p$ is a $k$-multilinear map on $T_pM$ and, as such, is always infinitely differentiable. Then you write $\omega = \sum \omega_{i_1\dots i_k} dx^{i_1}\wedge\dots\wedge dx^{i_k}$, differentiability (or smoothness) of $\omega$ is precisely differentiability of the *functions* $\omega_{i_1\dots i_k}$. These are functions, and not scalars, because they vary with $p$; a scalar would have to be the same for all $p$.

Comment: Mr. Shifrin thank you very much for your answer. You are right I didn't see exactly the link to the differentiability of the functions denoted above. But the part that puzzled me most was, that we had shown for a k-form that we might get it as linear combiantion of the basis elements. In this proof we hadn't the case that we have a k-form dependening on p. I tried to figure out the link between this proof and the definition above because I wanted to know how these $w_{i_1...i_k}$ are defined as funtions of p. May you tell how they are defined since it isn't completely clear to me?

Comment: Your basis $e_1,\dots,e_n$ for $T_pM$ is now $\partial/\partial x^1|_p,\dots,\partial/\partial x^n|_p$. Note that this varies as $p$ varies. You get $\omega_{i_1\dots i_k}(p) = \omega(p)(e_{i_1}|_p,\dots,e_{i_k}|_p)$. Just think about a simple example with $M=\Bbb R^2$. Take $\omega = x^1 dx^2$. Note that $x^1$ is a function, not a constant.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm going to think about it and give a sign in case of further problems.